# Preference seems to be ignored

Tags: magento2, preference, amasty

This is the class I want to get preferenced :
`Amasty\Shopby\Block\Navigation\Top\Navigation`

I've put some dump inside each files....only the test 3 is appearing when it shouldn't as ovverrided by the proference. Compilation is done. What am I missing there ?

This is the class content

```
class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{
    const PRODUCT_LISTING_SEARCH_BLOCK = 'search.result';
    const PRODUCT_LISTING_TOOLBAR_BLOCK = 'product_list_toolbar';

    /**
     * @return \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        var_dump("test 3"); die();
        $productListingBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock(self::PRODUCT_LISTING_SEARCH_BLOCK);
        if ($productListingBlock) {
            $toolbarBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock(self::PRODUCT_LISTING_TOOLBAR_BLOCK);
            if ($toolbarBlock) {

                $toolbarBlock->setData('_current_grid_order', null);
                $toolbarBlock->setData('_current_grid_direction', null);

                $orders = $toolbarBlock->getAvailableOrders();
                unset($orders['position']);
                $orders['relevance'] = __('Relevance');
                $toolbarBlock->setAvailableOrders(
                    $orders
                )->setDefaultDirection(
                    'desc'
                )->setDefaultOrder(
                    'relevance'
                );
            }
        }

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a preference on that class

```
<preference for = "Amasty\Shopby\Block\Navigation\Top\Navigation" type="Cpy\Category\Block\Navigation\Top\Navigation" />
```

And this is my custom class

```
<?php


namespace Cpy\Category\Block\Navigation\Top;


use Amasty\Shopby\Block\Navigation\Top\Navigation as AmastyNavigation;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

/**
 * Class Navigation
 * @package Cpy\Category\Block\Navigation\Top
 */
class Navigation extends AmastyNavigation
{

    public function __construct(Context $context, Resolver $layerResolver, FilterList $filterList,
                                AvailabilityFlagInterface $visibilityFlag, array $data = [])
    {
        var_dump("test 1");
        die();
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $filterList, $visibilityFlag, $data);
    }


    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        var_dump("test 2");
        die();

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the location of your di.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. confirm your di.xml file location is this one.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

2. Add the following into your `module.xml`

   ```
   <sequence>
        <module name="Amasty_Shopby"/>  
   </sequence>
   ```

Comment: I didn't had Amasty_Shopby in the dependence, it mus be it. Actually, what i'm really intenting to do is to remove the relevance sort to get the same sort in the search process than in the listing. But looks like there is much more in stake here. I will continue digging. Thanks !

Comment: If answer help please upvote and accept as solutions. so it will help other in community.